# How to Get Villagers To Breed Again

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

So I got my villagers to make about 10 babies. However, my younger sister killed all the babies, and they won’t breed again. Do I need to give the villagers more bread? Break and replace the beds? (The symbol that the villagers un-linked from the beds showed up on all the beds)

Comment: She didn’t actually kill the babies. I digured out what happened the next day. I found out why they weren’t breeding.

Comment: I will delete this question in 2 hours.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "Symbol" that appears when a villager unlinks from a bed, but rather green particles that appear when a villager **links** to a bed. All you need to do is give the villagers bread, or any other type of vegetable (Potatoes, beetroot, etc.) and they should breed again, given that there are enough beds for them to do so.

Comment: There are enough beds, and they already have bread from the first time they bred.

Comment: If a villager dies, does the game open up those beds again?

Comment: Yes. I had a couple of villager disappeared (due to a chunk border glitch) and villagers were keep breeding to fill the empty beds.

Comment: I found the villagers.

Answer (score 1):

A few thing could be happening the villagers could not have enough beds, not enough food, there isn't enough space above the bed (you need at least 3 blocks above the bed, or the villagers are unhappy and you need to either trade with them or win a raid.